# Modify array from TextField in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have this simple widget showing a textfield from which I modify a `List`:

```
Widget _elementTextField() {
    final TextEditingController inputNewElement = new TextEditingController();
    return Expanded(
      flex: 3,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 16.0, 16.0, 16.0),
        child: Container(
          child: TextField(
            controller: inputNewElement,
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Add Element"),
            onSubmitted: (elem) {
              // method 1 to update UI
              /*setState(() {
                newSet.elements.add(elem);
              });*/
              // method 2 not updating UI
              // newSet.elements.add(elem);

              print(newSet.elements);
              inputNewElement.clear();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

If I uncomment any of those method I won't see the `print` and the input won't clean up.

This is not related to any other widget and the `List` is just a simple `List` with one value on it.

This works fine with other widget I have but on that case I modify the value on a global provider. This is using just a `StateFul` widget

Comment: can you post code for whole widget?

Comment: the whole widget is quite big cause includes a swiper with different widgets in it. I moved the controller inside `class _NewSetPageState extends State<NewSetPage> {` which is the main one and this loads `_elementTextField()`

Comment: It's confusing just to see half code, you see. if possible just create a mini version of your widget which reproduces the same problem... so that we can help you out properly.

Comment: makes sense. Let me create a smaller version and I'll share the whole thing

Comment: thanks for guiding me to the correct way. I found many issues that I posted on a new answer

Comment: I'm glad you found the cause and the solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove `final TextEditingController inputNewElement = new TextEditingController();` from `_elementTextField()`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SamplePage extends StatefulWidget {

    SamplePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    State<StatefulWidget> createState() => SamplePageState();

}

class SamplePageState extends State<SamplePage> {

    final List<String> list = List();
    final TextEditingController inputNewElement = new TextEditingController();

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
    }

    @override
    void dispose() {
        inputNewElement.dispose();
        super.dispose();
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            body: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                    Row(children: <Widget>[_elementTextField()]),
                    Text(list.isEmpty ? 'Empty' : list.toString()),
                ],
            )
        );
    }

    Widget _elementTextField() {
//        final TextEditingController inputNewElement = new TextEditingController();
        return Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 16.0, 16.0, 16.0),
                child: Container(
                    child: TextField(
                        controller: inputNewElement,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Add Element"),
                        onSubmitted: (elem) {
                            setState(() {
                                list.add(elem);
                            });
                            print(list);
                            inputNewElement.clear();
                        },
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: I moved the controller as you suggested and try both method and none of them worked

Comment: I have updated my post and add more detail, basically a widget. Please, avoid call `_elementTextField()` inside `Column` because it will stretch vertically

Answer (score 1):

`TextField` itself is a `Stateful` widget, so when you call `setState` from inside the methods in `TextField` it will not update widgets outside of the text field.

To resolve this create the method in the parent widget to update the list and call `setState` from there, it will update the parent widget and the text field will be cleared.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find the solution above this answer, this was just my approaches to fix the whole problem:

Trying to recreate a smaller version of my page, I found this issue:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   if (widget.data != null) {
      // editing set
      newSet.elements = widget.data['mySet']['elements'];
    } else {
      // creating set
      ...
    }
```

This was executed every time I added something to the array so I moved the check to `initState()`.

Second error was this:

```
newSet.elements = widget.data['mySet']['elements'];
```

I had to modify this line and create my list without cloning it like so:

```
newSet.elements = []..addAll(widget.data['mySet']['elements']);
```

At this point, my list was adding more elements but it wasn't being displayed (I didn't mention this issue but I'll show the solution anyway).

I had this var containing some widgets:

```
_steps = [
      _step0(),
      _step1(),
      _step2(),
    ];
```

This list was being used to change dynamically a `Swiper` widget ([more info](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_swiper)).

So instead of doing this:

```
Swiper(
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
       return _steps[index];
    },
```

I do this now:

```
    Swiper(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              switch (index) {
                    case 1:
                      return _step1();
                      break;
                    case 2:
                      return _step2();
                      break;
                    default:
                      return _step0();
                  }
        },
```

Comment: the last change makes sense, as the widgets in the list are built only once when the list is built, but in `switch case` it builds every time the case is executed... awesome debugging, bro.